# Atualizar página ao submeter fomulário

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho este código e formulário e ao carregar em registar para inserir na tabela (que já insere corretamente) queria que actualizasse a página automaticamente para atualizar uma consulta que mostro antes ao utilizador.

```
<?php  

$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx"

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$pedido = $_POST['NumPedido'];  
  $data = $_POST['DataSaida'];
$funcionario = $_POST['Funcionario'];
 $funcao = $_POST['Funcao'];   
 $IdTipoLuva = $_POST['IdTipoLuva'];
$tipoluva = $_POST['TipoLuva']; 
$IdTamanho = $_POST['IdTamanho'];  
 $tamanho = $_POST['Tamanho'];
$quantidade = $_POST['Quantidade']; 
 $produto = $_POST['Produto'];
 $qtd = $_POST['QtaHigiene'];
$observacoes = $_POST['Observacoes'];
$estado = $_POST['Estado'];  


$sql = "INSERT INTO RegSaidaLuvas (`NumPedido`,`DataSaida`,`Funcionario`,`Funcao`,`IdTipoLuva`,`TipoLuva`,`IdTamanho`,`Tamanho`,`Quantidade`,`Observacoes`) 
VALUES ('$pedido','$data','$funcionario','$funcao','$IdTipoLuva','$tipoluva','$IdTamanho','$tamanho','$quantidade','$observacoes')"; 

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);
```

```html
<form name="form" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()" >

<h1><center><strong>Atribuição de Luvas</strong></center></h1></br>

<p><h5><strong>Número da Requisição</strong></h5> <input type="text" required="" id="NumPedido" name="NumPedido" /><br/></p>
<br/>
<label for=""><h5><strong>Nome Colaborador</strong></h5></label>
<select name="Colaborador">
       <option value="0">Selecione Colaborador</option>
        <?php
         $servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
          
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM InfoLuvas WHERE Ativo = 1 ORDER BY Funcionario ASC";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['Id'].'">'.$ln['Funcionario'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
    </select>
<br/>
<p><h5><strong>Data de Atribuição</strong></h5> <input type="date" required="" id="DataAtribuicao" name="DataAtribuicao" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"/><br/></p>
<br/>
<p><h5><strong>Observações</strong></h5></br>
<textarea type="text" id="Observacoes" name="Observacoes" rows="2" cols="90"></textarea><br/></p>
<br/>
<p><h5><strong>Estado</strong></h5>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="radio" name="Estado" value="Entregue" required>Entregue 
<p><input type="submit" value="Registar"/>
</form>
```

Comment: O INSERT é feito depois da informação que vc quer mostrar?

Comment: Sim, a consulta está logo no inicio da página e só depois vem o formulário

Comment: Alias, não acho uma boa prática carregar a página 2x só para mostrar uma informação atualizada, quando pode fazer isso de 1 vez.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito ser uma prática ruim ter que carregar a página 2x (dar um *refresh* após o *submit*) para exibir um dado atualizado que acabou de ser inserido no banco de dados.

No seu caso, o problema é apenas estrutural. É possível que as informações já venham atualizadas logo quando a página é recarregada no *submit*.

Altere a estrutura do código da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
// INSERT

// CONSULTA AO BANCO DE DADOS
?>
<form>
   FORMULÁRIO
</form>
```

Desta forma, com o `INSERT` antes da consulta, os valores vão sempre vir atualizados na consulta quando você fizer um *submit* no formulário.

Answer (score 0):

No form não está incluso a tag action onde irá enviar os dados via POST.

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="arquivo.php" onsubmit="return form_validation()" >
```

Substituir o arquivo.php pelo nome do arquivo que será enviado os dados.

E na página de destino, onde irá receber os dados, você aponta novamente para o documento que está o formulário. Como o exemplo abaixo:

```
header('Location: formulario.php');
```

Edited: Neste caso, apenas deve ser usado a função [header](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) do PHP.

Substitua esta linha:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);
```

Por essa:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
  header('Refresh: 1; url=index.php');
}
```

Apenas substitua o nome do arquivo pela certo.

Comment: Não está incluído a tag action, porque é tudo feito na mesma página, logo não preciso de chamar nenhuma ação.

Comment: @Desc neste caso, coloque o código restante da página. Assim vou conseguir entender melhor.

Comment: Dessa forma não funciona